# Choosing version of MikTex to use in TexMaker?

Tags: texmaker

I am trying to use \addbibresource{} which should be available in MikTex 2.9 but isn't in MikTex 2.8. I therefore downloaded and installed version 2.9.

Now I still get "undefined control sequence" and the log file says:

> LOG FILE :
>   This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-1.40.10 (MiKTeX 2.8)

I am using Texmaker. It seems to me, based on the logfile, like Texmaker is still using 2.8 even though I've installed 2.9. How do I tell Texmaker to start use the 2.9 version?

Comment: remove the 2.8 anyhow. That is pretty old and not maintained anymore.

Comment: I would, but I'm afraid I'll end up not being able to compile anything anymore. Once 2.9 is up and running I'll remove the 2.8. Fun fact: I've believed that I'm using 2.9 for >6 months until I ran into this.

Comment: I am surprised that you are still able to compile with 2.8.

Comment: Open texmaker and manually set the paths in options commands to the correct miktex 2-9 files.

Comment: or reinstall texmaker

Comment: `\addbibresource` needs `\usepackage{biblatex}`

Comment: You can keep 2.8 without problems if you have the space. At first check if miktex 2.9 is first in the PATH environment variable. (use e.g. `set` in a command line to show you the current settings.) Then check the settings in texmaker -- the best is if they don't use any hard coded path so that the environment variable is used.